# How many complex roots of $z^5-z^4-1$ have modulus $1?$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

> The number of complex roots of the polynomial $z^5-z^4-1$ which have modulus 1 are $\dots?$

I approached the question by opening up the complex number $z^5$ and $z^4+1$ separately and equating them for getting all the roots but upon doing that I got very unusual curves from which it is difficult to conclude the complex roots.

Comment: Hint: $z^4+1=e^{i\theta}\iff z^4=2e^{i(\theta+\pi)/2}\sin(\theta/2)$

Comment: the relation formed by transforming the polynomial in the variable theta still doesn't look solvable. I am not sure how am I supposed to manipulate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z$ be a complex root with $z\overline{z}=1$. Then $z^5-z^4-1=0$ and therefore $\overline{z}^5-\overline{z}^4-1=0$. Multiply the last by $z^5$ to obtain $1-z-z^5=0$. Together with the first equation this gives $z^4=-z$. Since $z$ is nonzero, then $z^3=-1$. We then check that the nontrivial third roots of minus $1$ have modulus $1$ and verify $z^5-z^4-1=0$.

Answer (score 6):

If $z \in \Bbb C$ satisfies $|z| = 1$ and $z^5-z^4-1 = 0$ then
$$
 1 = |z^5-z^4| = |z^4(z-1)| = |z-1|
$$
so that $z$ lies on the intersection of the two circles $|z| = 1$ and $|z-1| = 1$. That gives two candidates
$$z_{1, 2} = \frac 12 \pm \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \, i \, .
$$
I'll leave it to you to verify that these are actually solutions of the equation $z^5-z^4-1 = 0$. (It may help to notice that $z_{1,2}$ are third roots of $-1$.)